# Perl: save image from web

Tags: image, perl

I'm using this code to save images from a specific URL using [Image::Grab](https://metacpan.org/module/Image%3a%3aGrab). But the image gets saved in 0 bytes so there is no image.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Image::Grab;
$pic->url('hhttp://www.vikingskipet.no/cam_1.jpg')
$pic->grab;

# Now to save the image to disk
$time = time();
open(IMAGE, ">$time.jpg") || die"$time.jpg: $!";
binmode IMAGE;  # for MSDOS derivations.
print IMAGE $pic->image;
close IMAGE;
```

I hope someone can help me. I'm using cronjobs to run the script every minute.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` - unless you cut the sample down a bit too much before posting, `$pic` is un-initialized. (And check the url.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `getstore()` from `LWP::Simple`

Comment: I tried using that.

use LWP::Simple;
$time = time();
getstore("http://www.vikingskipet.no/cam_1.jpg","$time.jpg");

Does not seem to work. It does not save the image on the server at all.

Answer (score 6):

The main problem is that you haven't created an `Image::Grab` object. You should *certainly* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of all your programs, especially when you are asking for help with them. That will allow Perl to find and report simple mistakes that you may have overlooked.

This program does what you intended, as well as putting the file name into a more readable form

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Image::Grab;

my $pic = Image::Grab->new;

$pic->url('http://www.vikingskipet.no/cam_1.jpg');
$pic->grab;

my $file = do {
  my @dt = reverse((localtime)[0..5]);
  $dt[0] += 1900;
  $dt[1]++;
  sprintf "%04d-%02d-%02d.%02d.%02d.%02d.jpg", @dt;
};

open my $img, '>:raw', $file or die qq(Can't open "$file" for output: $!);
print $img $pic->image;
close $img or die qq(Failed to close "$file": $!);

print qq(Image file "$file" saved successfully\n);
```

Comment: @daxim: thanks for the suggestion, but I would rather leave the code as it was (using just `time()` for the filename) than introduce another module to this question - albeit a standard one.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra h on the http